# How to set expiry date in seconds for cookie in JSCookie

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm using the [JSCookie library](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) to save and load cookies.

Now I want to save a cookie with an expiry date. This is officially supported with days like the documentation. But how can I set the expiry in seconds or minutes instead of days?

So I have the following code from the documentation but this is for example only for 7 days:

```
Cookies.set('name', 'value', { expires: 7, path: '' });
```

Are there any possibilities to achieve this?

Comment: Of course it is... https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#expire-cookies-in-less-than-a-day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RTFM...

```
var inFifteenMinutes = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 15 * 60 * 1000);
Cookies.set('foo', 'bar', {expires: inFifteenMinutes})
```

Answer (score 0):

I've set the cookie the expire in 15 seconds.

```js
function createCookie(name, value) {
  var date = new Date();
  date.setTime(date.getTime() + (15*1000));
  var expires = "; expires= " + date.toGMTString();

  document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
}
```